# Error jsoup in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup

I am still receiving errors due to jsoup in eclipse. I have dropped the JAR in the project's tab, rightclick the JAR file and then chose Build Path > Add to Build Path but it still does not work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn38e.jpg

Could you please help me?

@Thank you for responses!
I have done as you advised me but it still does not work.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpUNm.jpg

I am just a beginner but when I am using other packages everything works, I have troubles only with this jsoup. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Please post text, not links to images. Looks like you don't have the library on your classpath. Your source is also in the wrong directory structure according to your declared class.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder named **libs** in the root of your project and put your jar files here. Then go to project **Properties**, under **Java Build Path** > **Libraries** click on **Add JARs...** and select you jar file, under the **libs** folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the following code as your class is inside the default package.

```
package org.jsoup.examples;
```